# joomla layout handling in custom component

Tags: layout, joomla, components

where do I set the desired layout in the following function if is getting called like

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$input->set('view', $input->getCmd('view', 'Myview'));
```

and I would like to be redirected for example to `/views/tmpl/edit.php`

**found it**

it needs to be declared by url structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use `&layout=edit` in the URL, or set it in the view using `$this->setLayout('edit');`